# How do I boot only off a USB drive (with no SD card inserted)?

Tags: pi-3, usb, boot, sd-card, hard-drive

Do I need a MicroSD card for my Raspberry Pi 3 B, or can I simply use a USB flash drive (and no MicroSD card)?

Comment: On a Raspberry Pi 3 B, [you need an SD Card simply to enable the USB boot bit](https://www.instructables.com/Booting-Raspberry-Pi-3-B-With-a-USB-Drive/#step1).